# .Net winforms control won't show up in IE

Tags: .net, html, controls

I’m developing a .Net winforms control to be hosted by IE in a html page. The following is setup on the dev box:

- Localhost is added as a CodeGroup to the Macine Security Policy:

  ```
      <CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust" Name=" OfficeLink"  Description="">
        <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="http://localhost/*"/>
      </CodeGroup>
  ```
- In IE9: localhost is added to trusted sites and the security level of trusted sites is low.

When I open the page containing the control in IE the control is downloaded to the temporary internet files. But nothing is displayed on the page, no .net error message and no ?FusionBindError!name file in temporary internet files.
Any ideas, how to resolve this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: And the answer is...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109642/loading-net-usercontrols-in-ie-with-net-4-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware, for this one to it disables all .Net controls in the browser:

http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?18600-ActiveX-and-CLSID-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240797/en-us