# Running C# User Control on Client Side from ASP.NET in Windows7

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

We are running an Windows Forms User Control .dll on client side from ASP.Net application. This was working fine for years on a Windows XP and now we are having issues when we upgraded the machine to Windows7. The control is not rendering on IE

I did observe using the Process Explorer that the .dll is not getting loaded on the client machine. Also observed through the Fiddler request that nothing happens after the dll call.

I beleive it is a security settings issue in Internet Explorer or Windows 7 which is causing the dll not to be loaded on the clients machine. I did add our website to trusted sites and also configured the .Net Framework configuration --> Code Groups --> Trusted zone --> Permission Sets --> Full Trust. Still no luck.

Comment: @mason: I believe the OP wants to host a Winform user control on the page. While it's very uncommon, and a source of lot of troubles, it [was possible](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx)

Comment: No we are using are loading the control on the client side using below  <object id='Worksheet' height='750' width='1230' classid='/irj/portalapps/RebateWorksheetPL/UserControls/RebateWorksheetControl.dll#RebateWorksheetControl.RebateWorksheet'/> </object>. I did check the F12 and there are no errors.

Comment: @user3403300: now in 2014, can't you migrate your old control to a modern HTML javascript App? It can be a bit complex, but sooner or later you'll have to leave the .Net control hosting.

Comment: Yes Steve, it is a WinForm Control on the web page. It was working fine on Windows XP and stopped working now on win7.

Comment: Did you try this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219180/call-net-assembly-from-object-tag-in-ie8

Comment: Are you running IE11 on your Windows 7 machine? Could be that they've deprecated this ancient technology by now.

Comment: No IE 9 on Windows 7 in Comptability Mode. Im going to try the comment by Rick.

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to be disrespectful, but what you describe here is nothing but a horrible monstrosity, Regardless if it used to work. Web applications consist of a Web Server delivering Web Content (HTML [ +JavaScript + CSS]) to a Web Client (browser). winforms is NOT a Web technology and does NOT belong into a Web Application. You can't really hope that thing to work in modern browsers. You should really think of ditching all that and create a proper solution for your UI. BTW, current HTML capabilities in 2014 are light years ahead of winforms, just like every other modern UI technology...

Comment: ... you should have no trouble in redoing whatever winforms-based UI using regular HTML and some JavaScript. If all of the above fails, you may want to use Silverlight, which at least was intended to be used on browsers since it's birth.

Comment: The answer provided by Rick did the trick. However now I'm facing another issue where the values set within the Param tag are not getting updated to the public properties set in windows control. I did write some event logs and found that the values are empty in windows 7, whereas the public properties have values in winXP. Any guess what could be wrong?