# windows user control ( 4.6.2 framework ) hosting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I have seen link 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191631/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx

I struggle with the issue about windows user control's not displaying in IE10. before windows user controls framework 3.5, it's working.  after changing the framework 4.6.2 doesn't show the controller. In the IE temporary internet files inside dll are downloaded and
`?fusionbinderror!name=wincontrols.dll`

So please provide me any solution

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334664/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109642/

Comment: Not a direct solution but those ActiveX controls should have been buried long time ago. They're not safe and of course support for them will diminish with every new release of frameworks and browsers.